# Ag Grid and Angular, how to do server side pagination?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to do server side pagination with Ag Grid (version 25.3.0), but it's seem not to be that easy.
I have a button with a click event that you trigger the search with a reactive form.

That is what I have until now:

**HTML**

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid 
   class="ag-theme-alpine" 
   [rowData]="dataSource.content" 
   domLayout=autoHeight 
   [columnDefs]="columns"
   [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
>
</ag-grid-angular>

<button (click)="doSearch()"> Search </button>
```

**TS**

```
     @ViewChild(AgGridAngular) agGrid!: AgGridAngular;
    
      gridOptions: GridOptions = {
        pagination: true,
        rowModelType: 'infinite',
        cacheBlockSize: 10,
        paginationPageSize: 10
      };
    
      this.form = this.fb.group({
         entityCode: [{ value: null, disabled: true }],
         businessUnitId: [null],
         firstName: [null],
         lastName: [null],
         mail: [null],
         isActive: [null],
       })
    
    
    
     doSearch() {
    const formClone = this.form?.getRawValue();

    this.dataSource = {
      getRows: (params: IGetRowsParams) => {
        this._userService?.getUsers(formClone).subscribe(data => {
          params.successCallback(
            data, data.totalElements
          );
        })
      }
    }
  }

  onGridReady(params: any) {
    this.agGrid.api.setDatasource(this.dataSource)
  }
```

I have no error in the console and I have no request to the service.

I think I have to put the getRows method inside the doSearch method, but I don't how to do this in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You should give these inputs to ag-grid in html like this

```
   <ag-grid-angular
   style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
   class="ag-theme-alpine-dark"
   [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
   [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
   [rowModelType]="rowModelType"
   [serverSideInfiniteScroll]="true"
   [pagination]="true"
   [paginationPageSize]="paginationPageSize"
   [cacheBlockSize]="cacheBlockSize"
   [animateRows]="true"
   [rowData]="rowData"
   (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
   ></ag-grid-angular>
```

and in Ts file

```
 export class AppComponent {
  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
   { field: 'id', maxWidth: 75 },
   { field: 'athlete', minWidth: 190 },
   { field: 'age' },
   { field: 'year' },
   { field: 'gold' },
   { field: 'silver' },
   { field: 'bronze' },
   ];
  public defaultColDef: ColDef = {
   flex: 1,
   minWidth: 90,
   resizable: true,
   };
  public rowModelType: RowModelType = 'serverSide';
  public paginationPageSize = 10;
  public cacheBlockSize = 10;
  public rowData!: IOlympicData[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent<IOlympicData>) {
  this.http
    .get<IOlympicData[]>(
      'https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json'
   )
  .subscribe((data) => {
    // add id to data
    var idSequence = 1;
    data.forEach(function (item: any) {
      item.id = idSequence++;
    });
    // setup the fake server with entire dataset
    var fakeServer = new FakeServer(data);
    // create datasource with a reference to the fake server
    var datasource = getServerSideDatasource(fakeServer);
    // register the datasource with the grid
    params.api!.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
  });
  }
}

function getServerSideDatasource(server: any): IServerSideDatasource {
  return {
    getRows: (params) => {
    
     var response = server.getData(params.request);
      
     setTimeout(function () {
      if (response.success) {
      // call the success callback
      params.success({
        rowData: response.rows,
        rowCount: response.lastRow,
      });
     } else {
      // inform the grid request failed
      params.fail();
     }
   }, 200);
 },
 };
 }
```